# Find $F'(x)$ of $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x^2}e^{t^2}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

For

$$
F(x) = \int_{0}^{x^2}e^{t^2}dt
$$

I need to find $F'(x)$.

The answers say its:

$$
F'(x) = 2xe^{x^4}
$$

I need help understand how they got to this. I try to find the integral of $\int e^{t^2}dt$ but its not working, i tried integration by parts and substitution method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $$F(x) = \int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$$

You are asked to find the derivative of $$G(x) = F(x^2)$$

By the chain rule,

$$G'(x) = 2x F'(x^2)$$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$F'(x^2) = e^{(x^2)^2} = e^{x^4}$$

Combining this, we get
$$G'(x) = 2x e^{x^4}$$

Comment: That looks familiar, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using fundamental theorem of calculus you have the following:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) \, dt =f(b(x)) \frac{db}{dx}-f(a(x)) \frac{da}{dx}.$$
So in your case we get
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x^2}e^{t^2}dt=e^{(x^2)^2}\frac{dx^2}{dx}-0.$$

NOTE: So to get the derivative one may not necessarily have to compute the integral first.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i think i understand now.

Comment: You haven't really dealt with the heart of the issue. It's not just the FTC, it's FTC + chain rule.

Comment: @zhw. I beg to differ in your characterization of the core issue. I was simply referring to the basic idea behind Leibniz rule so that OP can explore further (as Op was attempting to solve the integral first). One can always differ in the amount one thinks is sufficient to provide an answer or a direction. Perhaps you think it is insufficient, which is perfectly fine and thereby you did the right thing by voting it down :-)

Comment: That was well said. But what I saw was the OP having basic troubles, and I thought the answer needed more to it. At the moment I'm sorry about the -1.